# How to open a new activity once clicking on the login button?

Tags: android

I'm making a social media app using Android Studio. The problem I'm facing is that whenever pressing the login button and getting a "login successful" message, the app does not immediately open a new activity. I should click it again for it to do so. Here's my OnPostExecute code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

        try {
            if (result != null) {
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), educationalActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you set the onClickListener again?
after the "login successful" you can open target activity directly,
you shouldn't set onClickListener (if you set it again it means you should click it again)
change your code as below :

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    try {
        if (result != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), educationalActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: " cannot resolve symbol 'view' ". I should declare it in the OnClickListener, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The **AsyncTask** should be call on the `onClick()` event of button, you have called the button `onClick()` on the AsyncTask completion, which is **wrong logic**. For you, the `onClickListner()` is set the first time. The next time you click after the AsyncTask is complete, the intent is fired which takes you to next **Activity**.

Comment: I understand, but I get "variable 'result' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final". If I move the `result.get("")` after the `onClick()` event, the toast will be shown upon starting the new activity but the problem of clicking the button twice is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers stated, setting an `onClick()` event will require the user to press again in order to open the new activity. I found that declaring a View variable and referencing it to the login button solved the problem:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

        try {
            if (result != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), educationalActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```